# About bridging tokens

Tags: polygon, bridge, l2, polygon-bridge

Prominent tokens such as shibainu and worldcoin exist in polygon and Op as well as ethereum. Is this a bridge from L1 to L2 by token operators so that tokens can be traded in a more scalable environment?
Do they expect the bridge to L2 to increase token usage and value? Why not deploy to L2 from the outset?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a bridge from L1 to L2 by token operators so that tokens can be traded in a more scalable environment?

It is impossible to know and must be checked token by token. There is no rule.

> Do they expect the bridge to L2 to increase token usage and value?

Here on this forum, we cannot read other people's mind so we do not know what they expect. If I need to guess the answer is yes, because to use token you pay less fees on layer two chains.

> Why not deploy to L2 from the outset?

Again, we cannot know why projects did what they did unless they confirm it themselves.

Generally, Ethereum is more secure and has more liquidity than any of L2s.